# Datatables counter column won't order and search while it set to true in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datatables

So, I have this table

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="tabeljabatan" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr align="center">
            <th width="5%">No.</th>
            <th>Nama Jabatan</th>
            <th>Keterangan</th>
            <th width="16%" align="center">Aksi</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($masterJabatan as $mj)
        <tr>
            <td align="center"></td>
            <td>{{ $mj->nama_jabatan }}</td>
            <td>{{ $mj->keterangan}}</td>
            <td align="center">
                <a href="/jabatan/edit/{{ $mj->id_jabatan }}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
                <a href="/jabatan/hapus/{{ $mj->id_jabatan }}" class="btn btn-danger">Hapus</a>   
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and here is the JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var t = $('#tabeljabatan').DataTable( {
            "columnDefs": [ {
                "searchable": true,
                "orderable": true,
                "targets": 0
            } ],
            "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
        } );
    
        t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
            t.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
                cell.innerHTML = i+1;
            } );
        } ).draw();
    } );
</script>
```

Why is this order-able and searchable table not working? The table screen appears the order icon.
And, as you can see I already set the searchable and order-able to be true.

Comment: fyi, im using datatables built in with sbadmin2 bootstrap template, and i'm adding this javascript to add the counter column